# Can you utilize all M1 (Apple Silicon) cores for training data science models?

Tags: data-science, xgboost, lightgbm, apple-silicon, mini-forge

I've recently bought Macbook Pro with M1 Pro, and finally managed to install arm64 libs for data science with miniforge, partially following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-apples-new-m1-macbooks-for-machine-learning-f9c6d67d2c0f) article (P.S. remember to use only one package manager either conda (preferrably) or pip for package installation) For now running stacking regressor with lightgbm and xgboost using n_jobs = 8 (number of performance cores) gives the best performance output. This way it is using 8 performance cores. If you use n_jobs = -1 setting, it makes Mac use 2 efficiency cores and 4 performance cores for some reason.

**So the question is, is it possible to run it on all 10 cores?**